# RSS Feed Sticky Post?

Tags: rss

My latest RSS feed shows 20 posts for example, but I want to include a certain category no matter how old the post is (for example, my 'featured' post category), and also just get 1 latest post from this category.

I've been trying to look for plugins, but I'm not exactly sure what it would be called. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. What have you tried so far? Plugin recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Ah ok sorry. I'm quite new to WP development but I'm using this:

<?php $feed = get_the_content_feed('rss2'); ?>

which obviously gets all the content from the latest feed (depending how many I set). I want to also add a condition to say get the latest feed as above, but also include 1 latest post from a category ID (to always appear in the feed). Sorry I hope I'm making sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
/**
 * A sticky feed post from a given category
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176706/26350
 */

add_filter( 'the_posts', function( $posts )
{
    if( is_feed() 
        && $tmp = get_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'feed', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ) 
    )
        $posts = array_merge( 
            $tmp, 
            wp_list_filter( $posts, array( 'ID' => $tmp[0]->ID ), 'NOT' ) 
        );

    return $posts;
} );
```

where we prepend a given category post to the feed. Here you have to adjust the `feed` category slug to your needs. We also make sure that the sticky post isn't duplicated.

Comment: Hey that's brilliant - I would never have come up with that! Thanks for taking the time